# Move Layer between Parent and Child (z-index)

Tags: css, z-index

I have 3 DIVS. A Parent, a Child and a Layer (sibling of Parent). The Layer should appear between parent and child.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="layer"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.parent {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.child {
    z-index: 3;
    top: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.layer {
    z-index: 2;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PHwua/

strangely, i can't get the layer to appear between parent and child. On a live site, this works for some reason in all browsers (IE8-11, FF, Chrome) except Safari.
Now i can't even get the JSFiddle to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue probably has to do with the [stack(ing) order](https://www.google.com/search?q=stacking%20order%20css) of HTML elements.

Basically, `z-index` affects elements inside the same stacking context. The `parent` and `layer` boxes are in the same context; so their `z-index`es are evaluated first. Then the `child` box's `z-index` is evaluated against its stacking context (which nothing else exists in it since its a sub-context of `parent`).

If you take `parent` out of the stacking order (by making its position `static`, for example, or getting rid of its `z-index`), then `child` and `layer` will be in the same stacking context.

[Forked JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/JkLLu/1/)